# How to test Rest API which require authentication using Rest assured

Tags: java, json, rest, testng, rest-assured

I want to test a Rest API which require authentication, before getting the Json response.
 FOr exa. If i want to visit rest API:  http://192.168.xx.xx:9000/dashboards/all/list/m1/p1/sch1

then

if I am not already logged in , then this will redirect me to Login HTML page, and after login, this will show me the Json output.

Now I want to write a Rest assured code in java for same:
I dont know , whether this is possible to do login using this or not.

SO I written a simple code for same::

```
public class TestNGSimpleTest1 {

    @Test
    public void testAdd() {
            //expect().
            //statusCode(400).
            //body("Status", equalTo("Success")).
            //when().
            //get("http://localhost:9000/dashboards/all/list/m1/p1/sch1");
            //System.out.println("Response received is ::" +res);   
            Response res = get("http://localhost:9000/dashboards/all/list/m1/p1/sch1");
            assertEquals(200,res.getStatusCode());
            String json = res.asString();
            System.out.println("Response received is :: " +json);
    }
```

So here instead of getting the Json response, I am getting the HTML source page response.

So, my question is if possible, how to do login and get the Json response.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: for rest-assured see [this link here](http://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#Authentication) which shows how to do basic or OAut authentification or [this link here](http://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/issues/detail?id=87) if you need preemptive authentication.

Comment: Actually, I tried this link also, but the problem is Login page where it redirect is , an html page.. using ur link, this is just showing the HTML page still.

Comment: What type of authentication are you using? Just a login-page which contains a backing database call which checks the entered username and password - so no basic auth or OAuth? This seems rather strange though especially for a REST based web service which is primarily intended for being accessed by applications rather than humans (so no input in form-fields and clicking a submit button). What server framework do you use? CXF, Restlet, ...? Have you already tried to connect to your REST service using SoapUI?

Comment: I will update about it soon because I am not sure of the answer you are asking for. Wheneever I make a http request like : http://192.168.xx.xx:9000/dashboards/all/list/m1/p1/sch1  , then it redirects to a HTML login page where this ask for username and password. I will get more details by tomorrow and will update you. Thanks.

Comment: @RomanVottner   Discussed with our Dev team .. they designed the Rest API in such a way that for any Rest API request this will redirect to a HTML login page. They agreed to change this authentication behaviour in QA test environment but Is this the correct approach??

Answer (score 10):

If you are using default authentication from JIRA, then preemptive authentication is what you need. Below are the sample code.

```
RestAssured.baseURI = System.getProperty("baseurl");
PreemptiveBasicAuthScheme authScheme = new PreemptiveBasicAuthScheme();
authScheme.setUserName("admin");
authScheme.setPassword("admin");
RestAssured.authentication = authScheme;
```

The sample code will help you do the authentication before every request you send.

Comment: Worked perfectly for basic auth.

Answer (score 7):

This method works great. In addition to submitting the login credentials, it also verifies the 200 status code at the same time

```
given().auth().basic(username, password).when().get("/uri/").then().statusCode(200);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
given().auth().preemptive().basic(username, password).when().get("{yourApiURL}").then().statusCode(200);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
package jira_APIProject;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.authentication.PreemptiveBasicAuthScheme;

import static io.restassured.RestAssured.*;

import java.util.Base64;

public class TestBasicAuth {

    @Test
    public void auth() {
        
        RestAssured.baseURI = "https://jjjjjjj-home.atlassian.net/";
        PreemptiveBasicAuthScheme authScheme = new PreemptiveBasicAuthScheme();
        authScheme.setUserName("kkkkkkkkkk.kkkkkkkkkk@gmail.com");
        authScheme.setPassword("lllllllll8U1XLsXZ02927");
        RestAssured.authentication = authScheme;

        given().header("Content-Type","application/json")
        .body("{\r\n" + 
                "    \"body\": \"Updated on 22nd april.\",\r\n" + 
                "    \"visibility\": {\r\n" + 
                "        \"type\": \"role\",\r\n" + 
                "        \"value\": \"Administrator\"\r\n" + 
                "    }\r\n" + 
                "}")
        
        .when().post("rest/api/2/issue/10004/comment")
        .then().log().all().assertThat().statusCode(201);
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably looking for form authentication:

```
given().auth().form("username", "password"). ..
```

Optionally you need to provide an instance of FormAuthConfig as a third parameter to describe how your HTML login page looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me :

```
JsonPath response = RestAssured
.given()
    .header("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedString)
    .when()
    .get(GET_PUSH_API)
.then()
    .statusCode(401)
    .extract().jsonPath();
```

Reference - Example 14 : https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured

Answer (score 0):

```
public void LoginRequest() {
    RestAssured.baseURI = BASE_URL;
    RequestSpecification request  = RestAssured.given().auth().preemptive().basic(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
    response = request.get("​/Account​/v1​/User");
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.